# How to finish this Python bank program with while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the instruction.

> Write a program to simulate a bank transaction. There are two bank accounts: checking and savings.
>
> Start with checking_balance = 500 and savings_balance = 2000. Include four options for the user to do the following transactions. Print current balances (both checking and savings). Deposit (to checking only). Withdraw (from checking only). Transfer (from saving to checking only). Quit the program

This is what I have done so far. I'm at a loss on how to finish this program.

```
#author 
#date January 2, 2018
#title Bank Transaction 

def bank():
while True:
    checking_balance = 500
    savings_balance = 2000
    newCheck = 500 + 0

    choice = input("""Choose one of the choices below.
    d(deposit) p(print current balance) w(withdraw)
    t(transfer) q(quit): """)
    if (choice == 'q' or choice == 'Q'):
        break #exit loop
        end
        
    if (choice == 'd' or choice == 'D'):
        deposit = float(input("Put amount: "))
        newCheck = checking_balance + deposit
        checking_balance = newCheck
       # print("New checking balance is $%.2f"%newCheck)
       
    if (choice == 'p' or choice == 'P'):
        print ("New checking balance is $%.2f"%newCheck)
        
    if (choice == 'w' or choice == 'W'):
        withdraw = float(input("Put amount: "))
        newCheck = checking_balance - withdraw
        checking_balance = newCheck


        

    #wait = input("press any key to exit.")
```

Comment: make a bank account class with methods for all necessary actions on it(listed in your task) then create bank account object and do all necessary operations on it. And make a separate logic for interaction with user.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm sorry. I'm in my first programming class in my life in high school so what you're saying isn't comprehensible to me. At least not yet.

Comment: You should at least move the initial definitions of checking_balance, new_check, and saving_balance outside the while loop. Otherwise you're overwriting them every time the loop runs. And fix your indentation.

Comment: @atru Thank you for saying that I should take out the those three outside the while loop. Learned something new. :D I'll fix my indentation.

Comment: Glad to hear :) This fixed your code, right? The posted answer is not that intense - one especially good thing about it are the -= and += operators. Haven't you covered them? Best if you try to make it work by yourself now.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

take your assignment dude, But please dont ask to explain if you dont know the basic of python.. It was just a help

```
import sys

checking_bal = 2000
savings_bal = 500

while(1):

    print "________________________________\nPress 1---> For_withdraw_from_checking\nPress 2---> For_deposit_in_checking\nPress 3---> transfer_frm_checking_to_saving\nPress 4---> print_all_balance\npress 5--> For_Exit\n________________________________"
    input = raw_input("Please Enter your choice")

    if input == '1':
        amt = int (raw_input("Enter amount to be withdraw_from_checking account"))
        checking_bal -= amt

    elif input == '2':
        amt = int (raw_input("Enter amount to be deposit_in_checking account"))
        checking_bal += amt

    elif input == '3':
        amt = int (raw_input("Enter amount to be transfer_frm_checking_to_saving account"))
        savings_bal += amt
        checking_bal -= amt
    elif input == '4':
        print "Checking Balance--> ", checking_bal
        print "Saving Balance--> ", savings_bal
    elif input == '5':
        print "Exiting..."
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "Please Enter valid choice    Try again..."
```

Please run this code on your pc for better understanding. this is so easy.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is too advance for me. We don't use that much def. Our teacher said one while loop is good enough and just put if statements.

Comment: yes...! one while loop is present what else your teacher want

Comment: Ok, I have made the changes on above code Take that.
That is also very easy to understand

Comment: The question is tagged `python-3.x`. So `raw_input`is not supported.

Comment: In python 3 you should use "input()" insted of "raw_input" and also don't give any variable name == input otherwise it will conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Please keep in mind that the answers you give aren't just for OP but are for the community, so please try to explain your solution (as much as you can) as other people might be able to understand it.